# how to show that $ fgh \in L^1$

Tags: functional-analysis

If $f \in L^p,$ $g \in L^q,$ $h \in L^r$ where $1/p +1/q +1/r=1$, then how to show $fgh \in L^1$ with $\int |fgh| \leq ||f||_{L^p} ||g||_{L^q} ||h||_{L^r}$

Comment: Hint: look at the proof of the generalized holder inequality.

Comment: From what I can see of your history, you never provide any attempts or progress on your problems. And you have spammed several questions in a short amount of time, all being in functional analysis. Maybe you should contact someone at your uni, instead of looking for direct solutions here? It would be much more beneficial for your learning, and MSE standard.

Comment: yeah i will keep in mind this thing before asking questions for the next time..thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is as follows:

We know the inequality for two functions which is $$|fg|_1\le \|f\|_p\|g\|_q $$ where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. Here in this problem we have $$ \frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{r}=1 $$ So, we can do like this
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{r}=1\\
\implies \frac{1}{p}+\left(\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{r}\right)=1\\
\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{s}=1\ \ \text{where}\ s=\frac{pq}{p+q}
\end{align*}  So, we have $$\frac{1}{s}=\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}$$ or $$1=\frac{1}{p/s}+\frac{1}{q/s}.$$
         $$\int|fgh|\leq\|fg\|_{s}\|h\|_r\leq\|f\|_p\|g\|_q\|h\|_r$$

First we show that $\|fg\|_{s}\leq \|f\|_p\|g\|_q$. This is easy since $$\|fg\|_{s}=\left(\int|fg|^{s}\right)^{\frac{1}{s}}\leq(\|f^{s}\|_{p/s}\|g^{s}\|_{q/s})^{\frac{1}{s}}=\|f\|_p\|g\|_q,$$ where we apply the Holder's inequality (it is permissible since $|f|\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$, thus $|f|^{s}\in L^{p/s}(\mathbb{R})$). As a result, $|fg|\in L^{s}(\mathbb{R})$. Apply Holder's inequality again, we get the first inequality in far above.